# Why the code is keep calling mmap and munmap?

Tags: c, optimization

I was trying to optimizing a C code. When I using `strace` to trace the program, I found it is keep calling `mmap` and `munmap`. But this code is just doing operation over memory elements allocated using `malloc()`. Can somebody explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of `malloc()` probably uses `mmap()` on `/dev/zero` to allocate memory for the heap.

While `mmap()` is normally used for accessing ordinary files as if they're memory blocks, it can also be used with `/dev/zero`. Every time you map this file, you get a block of memory initialized with zeroes, so it's a useful way to add blocks of memory to the process.

Traditionally, this was done using the `sbrk()` system call. But this operation is fairly limited: it can only extend or shrink the data segment at one end. If you free lots of memory in the middle of the heap, you can't return the memory to the system because the objects at the end are still in use.

By using `mmap` with `/dev/zero`, the memory allocator can use several, independent blocks of memory for the heap. If all the objects in one of these blocks is freed, the entire block can be returned back to the system with `munmap`. That's why you see both of these being called frequently.

Comment: Why? I thoght mmap is used to map a disk space into the memory space. How could it be used for malloc?

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain how this works, and include the motivation.

Comment: Thanks, but why it still keep calling mmap and munmap when accessing the memory allocated with malloc?

Comment: It shouldn't do that just from accessing the memory. It should only do it if you're calling `malloc()` and `free()`. You could use a debugger to see what the program is doing when this happens. They might be called from library functions, like stdio.

Answer (score 2):

`malloc()` is not a system call, it's just a library function. Depending on your platform and C library implementation, you'll see some system calls used to actually get the memory.  One way to request blocks of memory from the operating system on a POSIX system is calling `mmap()`.  The library function can then do as it wishes with the memory, doling it out as it sees fit, and possibly freeing it later with `munmap()` if it's no longer needed.

Comment: Used to be you would see a bunch of `sbrk` calls instead, but apparently `mmap` is better on modern systems — maybe because it makes actually releasing memory easier.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not express my problem very clear. It is not doing mmap when calling malloc. But doing mmap when I was doing other operation on the space I allocated previously. For example, I allocated two big arrays to hold two matrix, and when doing matrix multiplication, the program will keep calling mmap and munmap, why is that happening?